# How to read numrange field in C#?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

How to read numrange field in C#?

I am facing with:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Can't cast database type numrange to String at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.GetFieldValue[T](Int32 ordinal) at
```

Comment: https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html  The .Net type is `NpgsqlRange<TElement>`.  If you want it as a string, then do a cast in your query (e.g. `rangecolumname::text`).